# C# Remove URL from String

Tags: c#, string

This seems like a really easy one but everything I try doesn't seem to work

say I have the following string:

```
string myString = "http://www.mysite.com/folder/file.jpg";
```

How can I process that to remove the URL and just leave "file.jpg" as the string value?

Thanks!

Kris

Comment: What would you like in the case of, e.g., `http://example.com/test.php?key=val` ? Or `http://example.com/test.htm#section1` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always use [`System.IO.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) methods

```
string myString = "http://www.mysite.com/folder/file.jpg";
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(myString); // file.jpg
```

If you do want to process more complex URIs you can pass it thought the [`System.Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) type and grab the AbsolutePath

```
string myString = "http://www.mysite.com/folder/file.jpg?test=1";
Uri uri = new Uri(myString);
string file = Path.GetFileName(uri.AbsolutePath);
```

Comment: This is one of my favorite hacks :) Use it all the time for parsing network ID's.

Comment: Be aware that the separator characters used by `Path.GetFileName` are platform-dependent, so there's no guarantee that `/` will be in that set on every possible platform. (Having said that, I'm not aware of any platform where .NET runs that doesn't include `/` in the set.)

Comment: At the same time there is no promise that `/` is the correct delimting character for a URI.  Path being  dependant on the platform should get the correct Slash (as a note it supports both `/` and `\`)... at least in the Microsoft version.

Comment: @Matthew: RFC2396 specifies that path segments in a URI *are* always delimited by `/`.

Comment: (Besides, if an RFC says to use `/`... wouldn't that imply that all versions of `Path.GetFileName(...)` would handle `/`)

Comment: @Matthew: No, because the RFC specifies URIs, which must always use the `/` delimiter. The `Path` class is designed to deal with filesystem paths, *not URIs*. The directory separator characters used by `Path` are implementation-defined (but by happy coincidence seem to always include `/` on all the .NET platforms that I've encountered).

Answer (score 4):

```
string lastPart = myString.Substring(myString.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```